# Basic Google Apis Requirement

Tags: google-plus

Is it necessary to have Google account to use google+ apis like google hangout etc ? Like with Google maps it is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do need a Google account to use the Google+ APIs. The reason differs based on the API you're interested in using, though.

**REST APIs**

You need an API key to use the Google+ REST APIs. You can acquired an API key from the [Google API Console](https://developers.google.com/console). You need a Google account to use the API console. This API key is used for many things including to manage your [quota](https://developers.google.com/+/api/#quota).

**Hangouts API**

The Hangouts API requires a Google account for two reasons. First, you must use the API console to [create your project](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/getting-started#create). Next, you must have a Google account to start a hangout.